# sub nav problems

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble getting my drop down menu to work. When you rollover the menu the 'drop-down' menu opens but it moves the content of the main menu, pushing it out of the way. Id there something I'm missing, this is driving me crazy trying to solve this! Please help!

CSS:

```
ul#topnav {
list-style: none; 
float: right;
width: 978px; 
border: solid #blue 1px;
}

ul#topnav li {
float: right;
display: inline;
}

ul#topnav li a {
float: right;
height: 20px;
padding: 0 15px;
font-family: GillSansStd-light, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none; 
text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul#topnav li a:hover {
background: #;
color: #ef5a53;
position: relative;
}   

ul#topnav li a:active, ul#topnav li a.current {
color: #000;
}

ul#topnav li span {
display:none;
color:#ef5a53;
}

ul#topnav li span a { 
width: 70px;
height: 10px;
padding: 5px 6px 5px;
background: #ef5a53;
font-family: GillSansStd-LightItalic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-color: #FFFFFF;
font-size:8pt;
}

ul#topnav li span a:hover {
text-decoration: none; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="topnav">
    <li class="tab1"><a href="page1.html">TAB1</a></li>
    <li class="tab2"><a href="page2.html">TAB2</a></li>
    <li class="tab3"><a href="page3.html">TAB3</a></li>
    <li class="tab4"><a href="page4.html">OUR CLIENTS</a></li>
    <li class="tab5"><a href="#">OUR WORK</a>
        <span>
        <table width="144" height="24" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="58"><a href="page1.html"><img src="images/image1.png" width="58" height="24"></a></td>
        <td width="86"><a href="page2.html"><img src="images/image2.png" width="86" height="24"></a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="tab6"><a href="page6.html">TALK TO US</a></li>
```

Comment: I have a rule of not helping people that use `<table>` for layout. There's no need!

Comment: @AlexThomas: All the more reason to help. Dave, it is curious that you would switch from list to table in the middle of the navigation. You can certainly use `<li>`s for the rest of the navigation, indeed there is no need for a table. [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXhvZ/) for anyone interested in helping.

Comment: Thanks Wesley/Alex, still finding my feet with all this advice really appreciated!

Comment: On reflextion, maybe I was a bit harsh. In my defence I knew someone would help and if they didnt I would have been happy to step in. I see you've accepted @Jordan Foremans answer, which whilst in principle "fixes" the issue, you really should redevelop the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and make the z-index of the dropdown higher than that of the main page, or use absolute positioning.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, had tried both these options including absolute positioning, though I've just realised that I needed absolute positioning on the Span AND the main nav - that sorted it!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider a dropdown css like this in your site?

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop2.html

Comment: Thanks McPepper - will look at this as an alternative - appreciate your time.